# Shallow serialization of Doctrine entities with JMSSerializer

Tags: rest, serialization, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle

I have a number of Doctrine entities with associations to other entities. I want to expose these entities in a REST API and have the associations be represented as IDs or URLs (ideally as [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html)). I've read through the docs and ran some tests with pre and post serialization listeners and handlers but I just can't figure out how to serialize associated entities to IDs and avoid recursion.

[This suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11964707/132208) of overriding the `DoctrineProxySubscriber` doesn't work for me because I'm loading multiple entity types in the same HTTP request and that automatically converts the proxies to real entities. For example if a `Room` has an associated `Building` and I just load the rooms then I get proxies but if I then separately load all the buildings then the proxies get converted.