# Doctrine EntityManager find object without retrieving all properties/collections

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Let's say I've got an entity called `User` with some properties like `firstName, lastName, age` and collection of `Posts`.

Is there a way to load this `User` entity with the `EntityManager` and `Find`-method without loading all properties/collections?

I'm using a `REST API` to retrieve the `User` and I want to seperate the calls:

1. **api/user/1** - should retrieve the `User` object with only `firstName, lastName and age`.
2. **api/user/1/posts** - should retrieve the `User` object with the properties and a collection of `Posts`.

I know I can use `QueryBuilder` and create seperate methods to retrieve the desired data, but I want to have it this way:

The scenario:

**api/user/1**

```
$userId = 1;
$user = getEntityManager()->find('entity\User', $userId);
return $user; // should only load the firstName, lastName, age properties.
```

**api/user/1/posts**

```
$userId = 1;
$user = getEntityManager()->find('entity\User', $userId);
return $user->getPosts(); // should load the firstName, lastName, age properties and the collection of posts.
```

I already tried 'Extra Lazy Load' functionality that is built-in Doctrine, without any result.

My code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name = "USER")
 * 
 * @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 * @JMS\AccessorOrder("custom", custom = { "id", "firstName", "lastName" })
 */
class User {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name = "id", type = "integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy = "IDENTITY")
     * @JMS\SerializedName("id")
     * @JMS\Expose
     * @JMS\Type("integer")
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name = "firstName", type = "string", length = 255)
     * @JMS\SerializedName("firstName")
     * @JMS\Expose
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     * @var string
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name = "lastName", type = "string", length = 255)
     * @JMS\SerializedName("lastName")
     * @JMS\Expose
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     * @var string
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity = "Post", mappedBy = "user", cascade = { "persist" }, fetch="LAZY")
     * @JMS\Expose
     * @var ArrayCollection<Post>
     */
    private $posts;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFirstName() {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function getLastName() {
        return $this->lastName;


    public function getPosts() {
        return $this->posts->toArray();
    }

}
```

The posts are always loaded after fetching the user object, even though I use fetch type lazy or extra_lazy.

Comment: as long as you have your entities defined with lazy loaded collections (e.g. posts in your user entity) and you're not accessing the posts of a user it's not loaded. so you'll have to provide more details, but we fought a lot to get it running, so I might be able to help.

Comment: @LBA added the user class!

Comment: Wild guess: Maybe lazy loading gets hindered by `$this->posts->toArray()`, (what's your use case for the transformation? I always keep them as `ArrayCollection`). Could you try with just returning the posts as  `$this->posts` and make sure nothing access a post.

Comment: @k0pernikus either removing toArray() or the getPosts() method doesn't work... I'm simply calling getEntityManager()->find('namespace', $id); and when I echo that in JSON it also shows the posts...

Comment: Are you JSON encoding the entire user object? It can be that the very serialization triggers the lazy load.

Comment: @k0pernikus Yes, I'm using JMS Serializer to JSON encode the user object. Why would that trigger the lazy load? :O

Comment: Maybe [this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11682928/457268).

Comment: @k0pernikus Gonna check it! I'll update u soon!

Answer (score 2):

Why not using Serialization Groups for it?

You can annotate your group (e.g. {'default'} and {'collection'} or even more specific {'posts'}.

Then you simply set your Serialization Context in your Controller and only the Group-related properties will be serialized.

See as well [documentation](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies#creating-different-views-of-your-objects)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Definitely going to use that I guess, but I guess that still triggers the lazy load?

Comment: The solution given is the right way to perform different exclusion strategy depending on the action of the request. You should also look at the [`@MaxDepth`](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#maxdepth) to limit the depth of the entries of your Post collection.

Comment: As long as you don't access the lazy-loadable attribute it will not be loaded. Using groups here with the JMS Serializer avoids calling unnecessary attributes and therefore their loading.

Answer (score 1):

You should write proper dql/querybuilder query and select only required for You fields.

It's not safe to return all posts on API just with `$user->getPosts()` - you will need pagination here.

You can also use [JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle). It gives you option to define needed property for Entity.

Comment: Added the user class!

Comment: ahh so you already used it ;) You didn't mentioned that in original question. But my answer still stays correct - `You should write proper dql/querybuilder query and select only required for You fields.`