# How to disable the automatic loading of all related entities during serialization?

Tags: symfony, jms, jmsserializerbundle

Symfony 4 with JMS.

The Parent class is associated with the OneToMany child class. In the repository, I get some parents, and some children (leftJoin with the condition). However, when trying to serialize Parents, JMS automatically gets all (!) Children from database, making additional queries to the database. How can I avoid this? Is there any option in the JMS config?

The only thing that comes to my mind is the `VirtualProperty()` version, in which I will filter the children already inside the entity. But this is not very effective.

**UPD**. 
I want to serialize this field, but not all child entities. Only satisfying the condition. In the repository I do `->leftJoin('p.children', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.foo = bar')`, but the serializer loads the elements that are not in the condition by separate requests. This is the problem

Comment: You can see this, but is no perfect solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575345/disable-doctrine-2-lazy-loading-when-using-jms-serializer

Answer (score 0):

Use serialization groups to choice which attributs you want and limit childrens with maxDepth ?

Comment: No, I want to serialize this field, but not all child entities. Only satisfying the condition.
In the repository I do `->leftJoin('p.children', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.foo = bar')`, and the serializer loads the elements that are not in the condition by separate requests. This is the problem